# AWS Glue not creating database or table in Data Catalog

Tags: apache-spark, etl, aws-glue, delta-lake

I have a glue etl job, where I want to create a database and table, if not exists.
But the database and the table are not created in the data catalog

In the etl, it reads data from s3 location and writes the transformed dataframe to the above created/existing table.

The code is as below:

```
glueContext.sql(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {bronze_db}")

glueContext.sql(f"""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {bronze_db}.{bronze_table} (
  id int,
  vaccine string,
  doses int
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '{dest_delta_s3}'
""")

dynamic_frame_read = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type='s3',
    connection_options={'paths': [source_s3_locations], 'recurse': True},
    format='csv',
    transformation_ctx=f"{bronze_db}.{bronze_table}",
)
data_frame = dynamic_frame_read.toDF()

additional_options = {'path': args['dest_delta_s3']}

dynamic_frame_read.write.format('delta').options(**additional_options).mode(
    'append'
).saveAsTable(f"{bronze_db}.{bronze_table}")
```

I have checked the permission and it has enough permissions. Not exactly sure what going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance